# S3 uploads not working in Dropzone

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dropzone.js

I'm uploading to S3 using Dropzone but it's only working in Firefox.  It doesn't work in Chrome, Opera, Safari or IE10.  It appears to be a problem on line 1410 in dropzone.js.

```
return xhr.send(formData);
```

Error in Chrome:
[image: dropzone-chrome-error]

Error in IE:
[image: dropzone-ie10-error]

Error in Opera:
Same as Chrome

My S3 CORS configuration is:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Is this a Dropzone issue or a S3 issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is the same origin policy. It only allows you to do XMLHTTPRequests to your own domain. Possible solution is to create a domain alias for Amazon S3: http://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: I know why it happens but how can I fix it?

Comment: Added possible solution to my answer.